# Difference-in-difference with Poisson regression

Tags: count-data, poisson-regression, difference-in-difference

I am trying to use DID method, but my dependent variable is count data. 
I tried to search if there was any paper regarding this matter, but I could find only those based on DID in probit and logit.

What I am making is Poisson regression where X*beta part of exponential is just a linear DID model. I will estimate with MLE, but I am not sure if this makes sense and how I should interpret interaction term.

I would really appreciate if someone can give me a hint.